# Vim - Custom Generic Syntax File

Tags: vim

I created a vim script to allow easy insertion of snippets when I code. I use placeholders of the form `<#placeholder#>` and loop through them. I would like to highlight the placeholders as comments so vim doesn't try to color those blocks :

```
syntax match abridgePlaceholder "<#.[^#]*#>"
highlight link abridgePlaceholder Comment
```

This works fine in a live session, but I tried to package it in a syntax file inside `.vim/syntax` but it doesn't work. I think vim doesn't load this syntax file at runtime.

I also tried putting that syntax in my `.vimrc`, but it didn't work neither...

So I would like that syntax to be applied to **all** filetypes. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It does not make much difference, but you should probably remove the `.`:  `"<#[^#]*#>"`.  I guess it _would_ make a difference if the "placeholder" text is optional and you want to match `<##>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You need to hook into the `Syntax` event; this gets fired whenever the filetype / syntax changes. You can place this into your `~/.vimrc`, but after `:syntax on`, so that the default syntax handling (which clears existing stuff) comes first:

```
:autocmd Syntax * syntax match abridgePlaceholder "<#.[^#]*#>"
```

The highlight needs to be defined only once:

```
:highlight link abridgePlaceholder Comment
```

#### Caveats

The syntax additions may interfere with the existing filetype's syntax, adding `containedin=ALL` may alleviate the problem, but there's no perfect solution.

#### Alternative

Alternatively, you could use `:match` / `call matchadd()`, which is completely separate from syntax highlighting, but this needs to be defined for each window (again, using `:autocmd`s).

Comment: The "Alternative" solution worked like a charm. I didn't think about using autocommads! Thanks for that!